# Kubernetes: Updating a Deployment Image with a TLS Ingress Resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm attempting to update the `image` for my Deployment. To this I am executing `kubectl edit deployment web` and am changing the `spec.template.spec.containers.image` property from:

```
gcr.io/my-project-id-1234/app:v1
```

To:

```
gcr.io/my-project-id-1234/app:v2
```

From the logs, I know the deployment updates fine. The problem I'm having is with the TLS ingress; here is my configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tls-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-secrets
  backend:
    serviceName: web
    servicePort: 80
```

And here is the result of `kubectl describe ing web` prior to the update:

```
$ kubectl describe ing                                                                                                                                                          
Name:                   tls-ingress
Namespace:              default
Address:                105.78.154.212
Default backend:        web:80 (10.0.2.3:8000)
TLS:
  tls-secrets terminates 
Rules:
  Host  Path    Backends
  ----  ----    --------
Annotations:
  backends:                     {"k8s-be-32171":"HEALTHY"}
  forwarding-rule:              k8s-fw-default-tls-ingress
  https-forwarding-rule:        k8s-fws-default-tls-ingress
  https-target-proxy:           k8s-tps-default-tls-ingress
  static-ip:                    k8s-fw-default-tls-ingress
  target-proxy:                 k8s-tp-default-tls-ingress
  url-map:                      k8s-um-default-tls-ingress
```

Before the update everything works correctly. But shortly traffic stops being successfully routed to my cluster. Describing the ingress now returns:

```
Name:                   tls-ingress
Namespace:              default
Address:                105.78.154.212
Default backend:        web:80 (10.0.2.3:8000)
TLS:
  tls-secrets terminates 
Rules:
  Host  Path    Backends
  ----  ----    --------
Annotations:
  static-ip:                    k8s-fw-default-tls-ingress
  target-proxy:                 k8s-tp-default-tls-ingress
  url-map:                      k8s-um-default-tls-ingress
  backends:                     {"k8s-be-32171":"UNHEALTHY"}
  forwarding-rule:              k8s-fw-default-tls-ingress
  https-forwarding-rule:        k8s-fws-default-tls-ingress
  https-target-proxy:           k8s-tps-default-tls-ingress
```

How do I properly update the Ingress when updating my Deployment like so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ingress points at a Service. The Service points at a set of Pods having some labels. The Deployment defines those labels on the Pods. Here's a list of what to troubleshoot:

1. Confirm the label selector on your Service matches the labels on the
   Pods your Deployment is creating. Otherwise the Pods created by the
   Deployment won't be selected for the Service and your Ingress will
   be pointing at nothing.
2. Confirm the Service is exposed as a `NodePort`. Otherwise the
   external Load Balancer from Google won't be able to reach inside
   your cluster.
3. Confirm the Pods are running/healthy. It's possible for a
   Deploymentto be updated but the Pods be unhealthy or in a CrashLoop.
   It's important for the application to respond with a `200` status
   code for `GET /`.
4. Create a firewall rule for the health-checks:

   ```
   gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-130-211-0-0-22 \
     --source-ranges 130.211.0.0/22 \
     --allow tcp:30000-32767
   ```

Comment: In the end, my app was to aggressively trying to upgrade to HTTPS and I was responding with a `301` instead of a `200` on `/`

Answer (score 0):

The ingress is reporting {"k8s-be-32171":"UNHEALTHY"}, that indicates the health check is failed on the backend service.

Make sure the app pods is up and running, check with

`kubectl get pods <pod-name>`

and

`kubectl get deployment <deplyment-name>`

If the app pods are ready and running, the ingress should connected to the new pods rs automatically but it may take a while depends on the health check parameters.